# Bitbucket prompt in Visual Studio Code search bar when running npm update

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket, credentials

We have a repository with our own bitbucket repo as a dependency.

in `package.json`

`"my-repo": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/my-repo.git",`

And everytime I run `npm update my-repo` i get a prompt in Visual Studio Code´s search bar asking for bitbucket username and password. I press esc two times to get rid of the prompt asking for username and password and the package updates as wanted.

[image]

This really annoys me and really appriciates if someone can help.